# ClearInterval Is Not Stopping

Tags: javascript, setinterval, getelementbyid, clearinterval

I'm trying to use setInterval to check for hash value change when a person clicks on a submit button. When the submit button is hit, the page will not change at all. Only the hash value is changed. I want to use the setInterval to repeatedly look for the hash value until it goes to page2 (in case the form values entered are incorrect). Once page2 is detected, it will clear the setInterval, but this part is not working.

```
var chkHash;
var hashval = window.location.hash;

var sb = document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function() {
    startHash();
}

function checkHash() {
   hv = window.location.hash;
   if (hashval !== hv ) { hashval = hv; }

   if(/page2/i.test(hv)) {
      clearHash();
   }
}

function startHash() {
   chkHash = setInterval('checkHash()', 5000);
}

function clearHash() {
   clearInterval(chkHash);
}
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, you're missing a right parentheses on the second conditional.

Comment: thanks! It was a typo on this one :)

Comment: You need to check there is no interval in `startHash`, because if you've already set one, the id will be lost and it will go on forever. So if you click twice, your code won't work in its current form. BTW, I suggest you look up `window.onhashchange` and plugins that do this for you. jquery binds this and shims for compatibility.

Comment: @davin, i think this is what's happening with the code. I notice it keeps running over and over again. Any suggestions to fix it? I have looked at window.onhaschange, but I read only the newer browsers support this. Thanks!

Comment: @jsmoove88, jquery uses a similar method to make the event work in older browsers. I suggest you use that.

Comment: @davin, thanks. I can't use jquery at this moment, because there are other codes along with this snippet, and i would need to learn from scratch. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements:

```
//Inside startHash, change:
chkHash = setInterval('checkHash()', 5000);

//to
clearInterval(chkHash); //Don't create multiple timers
chkHash = setInterval(checkHash, 5000);
```

I also recommend to add `var` before `hv = window.location.hash` inside function `checkHash`, so that the variable doesn't leak to the global scope.